# How to change the section numbering style to a) aa) and (1)

Tags: sectioning, subsection

I'm quite new to LaTeX and I want to know how to change the section numbering style for my subsubsections and so on to:
a)
b)
aa)
bb)
(1)
(2)

This is what I already have:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}   
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[margin = 1in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}




\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} 



\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}.}



\begin{document}                

\begin{titlepage} 
      \textsc{text\\}\par
        
   
  
       \begin{center}
        \vspace*{5cm}
      \textsc{text} \\
        [0.75cm]
        \textsc{text} \\
         [0.75cm]
        \textsc{text} \\
        [10cm]
        \end{center}
               
\end{titlepage}


\fancyhead[]{}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\newpage
\fancyhead[]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} 
\section*{text}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{text}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\section*{text}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{text}
\section{text}



\end{document}
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify your formatting objective. E.g., do you want section-level headers to be labeled a), b) etc; subsection-level headers to be labeled aa), ab) etc below section "a" and ba), bb) etc below section "b", etc; and subsubsection-level headers to be labelled (1), (2), etc? If not, how should the labels be formatted?

Comment: I would like the subsection-level headers to be labeled aa), ab) etc below section "a" and aa), bb) etc below section "b", etc; and subsubsection-level headers to be labelled (1), (2), etc. Thank you!

Comment: The instruction for the subsection-level header labels is confusing. Is "aa" really supposed to occur in both the `a` and the `b` sections? Please clarify.

Comment: "a" is supposed to be a subsubsubsection and "aa" a subsubsubsubsection. So it occurs under the a and the section.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no `subsubsubsection`, let alone `subsubsubsubsection`, level header in the `article` document class. Please clarify some more.

Comment: My sectioning already has this format:                                             \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}.}
And I would like the further subsection styles to be "a)" as a subsubsibsection, one further down "aa)" (subsubsubsubsection) and the last one to be (1) as subsubsubsubsubsection. I just don't really know how the section styles are called or if it is possible to change the style like so.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? With this setup, the `)` and `(` "decorations" that are shown in subsection and subsubsection level header don't show up in cross-referenes created by `\label` and `\ref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}

\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection)\space} % section-level
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection)\space} % subsection-level
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{(\thesubsubsection)\space} % subsection-level

\renewcommand\p@subsubsection{\thesubsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Uno} \label{sec:uno}

\subsection{Un} \label{sec:uno:un}
\subsubsection{Eins} \label{sec:uno:un:eins}
\subsubsection{Zwei}

\subsection{Deux}
\subsubsection{Eins}
\subsubsection{Zwei}


\section{Due}

\subsection{Un}
\subsubsection{Eins}
\subsubsection{Zwei}

\subsection{Deux}
\subsubsection{Eins}
\subsubsection{Zwei}

Cross-references to section \ref{sec:uno}, subsection \ref{sec:uno:un}, and subsubsection \ref{sec:uno:un:eins}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very near to what I was looking for. I understand now how it works.